# Ionic click not triggering in chrome emulator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My HTML is as follows:

```
<ion-scroll has-bouncing="false">
    <div ng-repeat="data in collection">
        <div ng-click="fn">click me</div>
        <a ui-sref="statename">link</a>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

The `ng-click` and link click is not working in Chrome emulation mode. Without emulation, it works fine.

If `ion-scroll` is removed, it works.

Comment: Does it throw any errors?

Comment: why do you have a list in a scrolling view?

Comment: @DaniloValente: No errors

Comment: @AaronSaunders: Its a long list and I already have an ion-content in my page.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem,
I had used a script to enable swiping on touch events on web page. which because of its coding implementation did not allow click events to function.

So solution i took,

I am achieving the same functionality by combination of touchstart, touchmove and touchend.

for example I wished to hide the paragraph on click of div on which swipe was enabled.
So when i clicked on div, click event was not registering, because i have script which is enabling swipe event on div.
In such case two solutions: modify the script so that click event is not affected.
or achieve click's purpose using combination of touchstart,move and end.

In other words your problem is iconic click script. 
Thanks to Google chrome emulator it identifies the problem right at development stage no need to go to actual device to check.
Thank you